# Bad readable wms layer on android - leaflet

Tags: android, leaflet, geoserver, wms

I need consume my WMS on leaflet and display it in web view. When I open my leaflet app in broser is pretty pure and readable. When same code run in android, it is much worst readable. I've tried add `detectRetina: true` to wms layer, but text was very small, and worst readable as now. On the images you can see differents.

Here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>LEaflet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/leaflet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

</head>
<body style="padding:0; margin:0; height: 100vh; width: 100vw;">

<div id="map" style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw;"></div>


</body>

<script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>

<script>
    var map = L.map('map', {
        minzoom:13
    }).fitWorld();

    var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://10.0.2.2:8080/geoserver/TEST/wms?', {
        layers: 'TEST:MyBaseLayer'
        //detectRetina: true
    }).addTo(map);

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to resort to the trick of having tiles double the size, with a `zoomOffset` of -1, i.e.:

```
var tileLayer = L.tileLayer(tileUrlTemplate, {
  tileSize: 512,
  zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(map);
```

Check the [Leaflet documentation for `L.TileLayer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#tilelayer) about those options. They apply to `L.TileLayer.WMS` as well.